# Merge tags [lighting-fixture] and [light-fixture]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm just passing it along that there is a "lighting-fixture" tag and "light-fixture" tag. As much as I know, these should be combined as they're one and the same.

The "light-fixture" tag is the one that has the most use and a description.

Comment: Please don't edit the posts to try to replace the tags; after the merge, [your suggestions](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/47336/tfk?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) were the same as the original versions of those posts, making them pointless.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure if it covered old posts or just new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. I've merged them, and you should only see [light-fixture](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-fixture) in future.